# Python algorithm/function: return all of the operational combinations of the digits of an input number which equal a target number

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I am tasked to produce a function f which, given an input number and target number, will return all operational combinations (+, -, /, * and joining digits) of the input which make the target number. For example if the input and target numbers are 115 and 16, the program should return `11+5=16`. Inputs f(123,6) should yield `1+2+3=6` and `1*2*3=6`. f(12301,6) should return `1+2+3+0*1=6`, `1+2+3-0*1=6`, `1*2*3+0*1=6`, `1*2*3-0*1=6`, `1+2*3+0-1=6`, and `1+2*3-0-1=6`.

Here is my attempt so far. I tried to approach this recursively, but am having trouble developing a solid algorithm. Is a recursive algorithm the correct way to approach this problem?

```
"""
creates a list of the integers associated with input number and returns all the
ways that list of numbers can be ordered with +-*/ operators to form target_num
base specifies which number system is being used (base 10 is default)
"""
TASKS = ['add','mul','sub','div','con']
def consec_op_types(num_in, target_num, base = 10):

    # get digits
    digits = []
    while num_in >1:
        next_smallest_number = num_in % base
        num_in = num_in / 10
        digits.append(next_smallest_number)
    digits.append(num_in)
    digits.reverse()

    '''
    A recursive scheme is used to find the combinations.
    Each function call in turn calls +-/* operators as well as just using this number with the one next to it
    '''

    # accepts list of operators used, references digits from above
    def show_results(vals):
        # print [item for sublist in zip(vals,digits) for item in sublist], ' = ', target_num
        print ''.join([str(v) for v in vals]), '=', target_num


    def find_number(num_list,total= 0,task= 0, result = []):
        print 'total:',total
        if num_list == [] :
        #    if total != 0: print total, result
            if total ==target_num: show_results(result)
            return

        if total==0:
           if task == TASKS[3] or task == TASKS[1]: total = 1

        #print "result = result+['+']",result+['+']
        #print 'total:',total
        if task in TASKS:
            current_num = num_list[0]
            num_list = num_list[1:]
            result.append(current_num)
        if task == TASKS[0]:
            return find_number(num_list, total + current_num,  0,  result+['+'])

        if task == TASKS[1]:
            return find_number(num_list, total * current_num,  task = 0,result = result+['*'])

        if task == TASKS[2]:
            return find_number(num_list, total + current_num, task = 0, result = result+['-'])

        if task == TASKS[3]:
            if current_num != 0: return find_number(num_list, total / current_num, task = 0, result = result+['/'])

        if task == TASKS[4] and len(num_list)>1:
            print 'ok.... num_list is ',num_list,' and current num is ',current_num
            print '--->',[10*current_num + num_list[0]]+num_list[1:]

            return find_number( [10*current_num + num_list[0]] + num_list[1:], 
                                 total,  0, result[:-1])

        #find_number(num_list, total, TASKS[0], result)
        for tk in TASKS:
            find_number(num_list, total, tk, result)
    find_number(digits)

# Object oriented idea (Not used, here to show I tried to implement it)
# class digit_tree_node:
#     def __init__(self, total = 0, recs = [], real_num):
#         self.value = total
#         self.records = recs
#         self.true_val = real_num
# 
#     def add_num(self, new_num):
#         addition = digit_tree_node(self.value+new_num)
# # #
```

Comment: What is the range of your input and target number?

Comment: Less than 1,000,000 and 1,000.

Answer (score 1):

Since the range of input number is `n < 10^6`, max number of digits in input are 6. So, there are at most 5 places where you can put a symbol. So, you can try the brute force approach. (Actually, while using recursion, you are indeed trying brute force (calculating all possibilities)).

So, you can select 0,1,2...or 5 places at a time to put a symbol.

- Selecting 0 places, ie. input number = target number, eg. (123,123)
- Selecting one position, which is 5C1 (max), and 4 possibilities to go with it. This makes 20 possibilities.
- Now, select two places and try all combination of symbols, which will be (at max) 5C2*4^2 = 160

Similarly, selecting 3 places takes 640, 4 places takes 1280 and all 5 places takes 1024 possibilities. So, worst case, you calculate ~3000 possibilities (which is totally feasible).

So, for selecting places to put symbols, use bit-mask of length = length of input. Then, once you have selected, try all symbols, calculate it and if it matches, print it and viola !!

Comment: I hoped that my code would work for any size data set, and wrote it with this in mind. Is there a way to solve this problem in a more efficient manner than the "brute force" approach?

Comment: Well, I'm not very sure about that. It is because, you have to see every possibility at least once, because, if you leave any, that can be a possible +1. So, whatever be the data set, you will need to search all.